# Word XML - XSLT to HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, unicode, ms-word

I have Word XML files that I convert to html with the use of an XLST file. I need to convert Wingdings symbols in Word to Unicode during the conversion. I have the following code in my XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="w:sym">
    <xsl:choose>          
        <xsl:when test="@w:char='F0FE'">
            <span>&#9745</span>
        </xsl:when>            
        <xsl:when test="@w:char='F054'">
            <span>&#9746</span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <span>
                <xsl:attribute name="style">
                    font-family:<xsl:value-of select="@w:font"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="starts-with(@w:char, 'F0')">
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;</xsl:text>#x<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@w:char, 'F0')"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="starts-with(@w:char, 'f0')">
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;</xsl:text>#x<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@w:char, 'f0')"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;</xsl:text>#x<xsl:value-of select="@w:char"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </span>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

My problem is that  I get an error in Microsoft Web Developer Express with the span blocks saying invalid character in decimal number. Any ideas on how else to use the unicode symbols and have them convert to html correctly?

Comment: I added a semi-colon after the unicode but when I open the html, I just get a ? where the unicode symbols should appear.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should have a semicolon after the number - otherwise they won't be character entities.

As for why you're seeing "?" instead of the actual glyphs, this depends on whether the font being used by the program (MS Web Developer Express?) contains glyphs for the codepoints being used. Your data may be correct, but not every font or program will be able to display all the characters.

[This page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2611/fontsupport.htm) lists some fonts that support Unicode character 9745 (x2611). Your browser shows it as: ☑

Comment: When it is converted to html, it actually changes the html to a '?'. If I could get the html code to be "<span>&#9745</span>, it would be fine.

Comment: @Sean: That should be `<span>&#9745;</span>`

Comment: @Sean: How do you _know_ the output is a real question mark? If it is, what is the output encoding from the server?  If the server believes it is sending ISO-8859, then it will substitute question marks for characters it cannot send.

Comment: I figured it out, in the xslt, I needed to use <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"></text> around the character.

Comment: @Sean - I'm a little dubious. If you're outputting `<span>&#9745</span>`, that's not well-formed HTML. You need the semicolon. And the vast majority of the time, d-o-e is not the right way to get something done in XSLT.

Comment: The html is from Word so its poorly formatted to begin with. I am just trying to make it work a little better so it displays in other browsers properly.

Comment: @Sean, I'm confused... I thought you were getting XML from Word and converting it to HTML yourself. Also, my previous comment was not referring to formatting but to correct markup. `&#9745` is a syntax error in HTML, and I would not expect it to display anything, but some HTML parsers are very lax.